# Connecting WCF service from an application which is behind proxy - Testing simulation

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5, proxy, wcf

I have an WCF Client application which connects to WCF service. I need to test the behavior of this application in the case the client machine is using a proxy.

My test environment does not use a proxy, so how can I simiulate this scenario such that I can confidently test this case?

Comment: is this a .NET 4.0 client application? Typically WCF clients will use a proxy if the client machine is configured to use one. That is, if they are using a proxy and IE (Internet Explorer) is configured to use this proxy as well, then the WCF client will use this proxy also (unless configured otherwise). The BasicHttpBinding (in the confic file) has a  UseDefaultWebProxy element which is true by default. So even if you don't see in your config file (on the client) it is true.

Answer (score 1):

Typically WCF clients will use a proxy if the client machine is configured to use one. That is, if they are using a proxy and IE (Internet Explorer) is configured to use this proxy as well, then the WCF client will use this proxy also (unless configured otherwise). The BasicHttpBinding (in the confic file) has a UseDefaultWebProxy element which is true by default. So even if you don't see in your config file (on the client) it is true

You could use a public proxy server yourself so you test to make sure. There are many free and paid for proxy servers you can use. For example
http://www.publicproxyservers.com/ is a paid for proxy server.

Basically you'll use a proxy to get out onto the internet and so you'll need to configure your IE to use this proxy. When you next run your WCF Client, it will use this proxy as well.

Here is a website that lists some proxys. You'll find the ip address/post and username/password to use. So you can configure your test machine to use one of these proxies and test away.

Note: Free proxy servers are suspect. Be very careful when you use them and there is no telling what they do (in terms of grabbing data). So use at your own risk.